# Tokenization with spaCy

Tags: string, dataframe, nlp, spacy, text-mining

I'm a rookie in Python and I hope to find here help for my text analyse project.
I'm trying to tokenize several text elements which I imported from an excel in python spyder. Each text element is in a seperate row.

I tried this code but it doesen't work.

```
import spacy

df = txtdf.head()
df2 = df['Textelements']

from spacy.lang.de import German

nlp = German()
doc = nlp(df2)
tokens = [token.text for token in doc]
print(tokens)
```

And I get this error in the console:

> ValueError: [E1041] Expected a string, Doc, or bytes as input, but
> got: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Answer (score 2):

`nlp(df2)` expects a single string/document to process, but it receives a pandas Series of strings. Try to batch process the column:

```
docs = nlp.pipe(df2)
for doc in docs:
    tokens = [token.text for token in doc]
    print(tokens)
```

Or (not recommended because its slower) iterate over the column and call the processing for each row:

```
for row in df2:
    doc = nlp(row)
    tokens = [token.text for token in doc]
    print(tokens)
```

If you really do want to process the entire column as one big blob of text you have to implement a way to join it all into one text beforehand.